# Velocity of an oscilating particle

Tags: calculus

I am working on an assignment where I have an equation in which I am to calculate X. The equation, which describes the velocity of a oscilating particle, is as follows.

$v_x = 52cos(700t+0.2\pi)$

The assignment states that if the particle has $t=0.001$, then $x=2$. The assignment is to calculate $x$ when $t=0.002$.

Frankly I am lost. I have tried a few approaches to the problem, but I can't seem to get it straight. I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: In calculus you can differentiate and integrate. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Mnifldz we are currently working with integrals so I think that is what we are supposed to do.

Comment: Good.  Take the integral then.

Comment: @Mnifldz I don't understand how to calculate x? would not integrating give me $v_x$?

Comment: No.  $v_x$ is your velocity and $x$ is your position.  What is their relationship?  What variable would you be integrating with respect to?

Comment: @Mnifldz is it with respect to t that i should integrate ?

Comment: Yes.  It's helpful if instead of writing just $v_x$ and $x$, you could write $v_x(t)$ and $x(t)$.  The latter is more suggestive of what needs to be done in the problem.

Comment: @Mnifldz would you please show me, I'm not sure if I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the relationship between position $x(t)$ and velocity $v(t)$ is given by $v(t) = \frac{dx(t)}{dt}$.  If given the velocity $v(t)$ initially then one can find the position by $x(t) = \int v(t)dt + c$ where $c$ is a constant, determined by initial conditions [Hint: your initial condition in this case is that $x(0.002) = 2$].

Now, do you understand the general concept?  Is your problem in the technique of integration?  You might want to see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions

Comment: thanks I think I solved it :D